# How to enable "Auth Login" for Exchange Server 2016

Tags: exchange-server

I need to enable "Auth Login" method on an Exchange Server 2016. I see multiple examples showing a response of the ehlo command that contains something like:

> 250-AUTH=LOGIN

However my server shows this output:

> 250-mail.mydomain.com Hello [::1]
>
> 250-SIZE 37748736
>
> 250-PIPELINING
>
> 250-DSN
>
> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
> 250-STARTTLS
>
> 250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-BINARYMIME
>
> 250 CHUNKING

I have Basic authentication and Integrated Windows authentication both enabled on the connector.

[image: Connector security properties]

If I remove the Integrated Windows authentication this line disappears:

> 250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM

However, AUTH LOGIN still does not appear.

What settings are needed to enable AUTH LOGIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncheck the option:

"Offer Basic authentication only after starting TLS"

according to the Microsoft forum entry [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bf75da0a-9c8d-4884-a335-718614ba9d90/enable-auth-login-on-exchange-2013-receive-connector?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does not seam to change anything. Do you think any services need a restart?

Comment: You might try to re-start the transport service

Comment: Had to also remove Windows authentication and then it appeared in the list. No service restart needed.

Comment: What if I want to only allow modern OAuth2 authentication for SMTP but not basic authentitcation? How do I do that?